# WPBakery Post Grid Custom Query

Tags: wordpress

I am using WPBakery and I would like to use the Post Grid to display the child pages of the current page. I understand that I can use a custom query within WPBakery, however, I am struggling with fetching the current post ID which is accepted by WPB.

I have a custom post type called 'partners' and some have child pages which I would like to bring through using the grid.

I'm looking to turn this into a custom query which is accepted by WPBakery.

```
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'partners',
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

When use the Post Grid to display the child pages of the current page.
I use string:`post_parent="parent page ID"&posts_per_page=-1&post_type=page`